# Uploading files impossible on Heroku with Python?

Tags: python, heroku

Heroku doesn't allow you to upload files, they rather you upload them to a cloud storage service such as Amazon s3. But, in order to upload a file to s3 using Python the file needs to be saved as you need the string path...?

Comment: It's not "impossible", but it's not persistent. Better options are to save to S3 from memory on the server or [have your users upload files directly from their browsers to S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Heroku when saving files is that they have [ephemeral filesystem](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), which means that the file you have stored on `Heroku` that doesn't belong to initial `git` repository, will be deleted after `dyno` restart which happens every 24h I think.

But they are still allowing you to store the file for ~24h (or until next dyno restart), with this in mind, you can store locally in some `/tmp` dir for quick reference or you can upload the file to `AWS S3` bucket using `boto3` library.

Answer (score 0):

Only the relative filepath is saved as a string in the database when you use FileField or ImageField. Django rely on what you defined in the MEDIA_ROOT (the url for you S3 storage bucket, for example) and append the relative url with the name of the file (uploads/file.txt, for example) to build the complete path to the file. Check on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)